# NSArray contains a string with missing quotes when converting from JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

I have an `NString` that contains the following JSON:

```
str = [{"id":32,
        "date_time":"02-09-2016;23:31:29",
        "message":"tidal wave"},
       {"id":33,
        "date_time":"02-09-2016;23:33:52",
       "message":"mashup"}]
```

I converted this to an `NSArray`:

```
jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];
```

However, when I `NSLog` the jsonObject, I get the following:

```
jsonObject = (   
        {
        "date_time" = "02-09-2016;23:31:29";
        id = 32;
        message = "tidal wave";
    },
        {
        "date_time" = "02-09-2016;23:33:52";
        id = 33;
        message = mashup;
    }
)
```

Why does the value in message, `tidal wave`, have quotes around them but not `mashup`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is just how it's being logged. The keys "id" and "message" are strings.  `jsonObject` is a `NSArray< NSDictionary<String, id> *> *`, not related to JSON any more.

Comment: Thanks Lou. 2 questions. First, if id and message keys are strings, then what type is date_time since date_time has quotes around them? Second, how would I be able to convert mashup (not sure what type that object is) into an NSString? Thanks

Comment: mashup is probably a string.  You can `po jsonObject[1][@"message"].class`